# How to convert datatable to list with out List of object or List of class

Tags: asp.net

I have a DataTable dtStudent which have columns like stuid,stuname,stuclass and so on like that so many columns are there and assume i have 10 rows.we dont know how many columns will be present in datatable it may vary depends on functionality.
Now how do i convert datatable to List of string,string,string,string,  like that without using List of class becuase unknown columns in the datatable.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through `DataTable` rows and collect data.
You can use `DataTable.Columns` for getting column names and using them to get row cells.

```
List<string[]> result = new List<string[]>();

foreach (DataRow row in rightsTable.Rows)
{
    string[] cells = new string[rightsTable.Columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < rightsTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        cells[i] = row[rightsTable.Columns[i].ColumnName].ToString();
    }
    result.Add(cells);
}
```

**Update:**

OK now. I have forgotten about `ItemArray` property. It simply returns the array of `object` stored in a row. You just need to execute `ToString()` on it.
You can use this one instead as it is more convenient and fast.

```
List<string[]> result = new List<string[]>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    list.Add(row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
}
```

Or even shorter using LINQ:

```
List<string[]> result = dt.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => row.ItemArray
        .Select(x => x.ToString())
        .ToArray())
    .ToList();
```